# Ace Editor: Prevent markers to be shown for folded lines

Tags: ace-editor

I have several logs combined in Ace editor, for example:

```
/// daemon start
build log: content
build log: content 
indexing log: content
/// daemon end

content

/// daemon start
build log: content
build log: content 
indexing log: content
/// daemon end
```

The first `daemon start...daemon end` block is folded via custom [folding function](https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/code-folding) like that:

```
/// daemon start [folded region]

content

/// daemon start
build log: content
build log: content 
indexing log: content
/// daemon end
```

every `build log` and `indexing log` line is highlighted via `screenLine` marker like that:

```js
editor.session.addMarker(range, "cssClass", "screenLine", false)
```

In "real world" example this leads to unnecessary highlighting of folded regions. See this example:

[image]

How to prevent folded region to be highlighted and remain highlighting for unfolded region only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Ace editor 1.5.2 in the scope of https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/4687